# ORACLE SQL APEX using sequence numbers gives an missing expression error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I created sequence for manager first.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE manager_seq
START WITH 200
MAXVALUE 299
CYCLE 
CACHE 10;
```

Then I inserted some values using .NEXTVAL

```
INSERT INTO manager
VALUES (manager_seq.NEXTVAL,'')
```

When I try to query with where statement it says    ORA-00936: missing expression

```
select * from manager where number = 201;
```

Why it isn't working with sequnce numbers how can I use them?

Comment: You'd use `manager_seq.currval` to get the last value the sequence generated in the current session.  I'm hard-pressed to imagine that you really want a sequence to have a maximum value of 299-- every time the sequence ages out of cache, you're going to lose up to 10 cached values so you're going to be cycling pretty regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column name can't be `number`, that's a reserved word - reserved for **datatype**. For example:

```
SQL> create table manager (id     number,
  2                        number number);       --> this
                      number number)
                      *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Therefore, post table description (so that we could suggest what to do) or use valid query.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/olaxs/reserved-words.html#GUID-7AA16E7F-A9CC-47EE-94B0-05C518D69BA7) as an identifier then you need to quote it everywhere you use it. So, if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE manager (
  "NUMBER"  NUMBER,
  something VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

Then you insert rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO manager VALUES (manager_seq.NEXTVAL,'');
INSERT INTO manager VALUES (manager_seq.NEXTVAL,'');
```

Then, if you use an unquoted identifier:

```sql
select * from manager where number = 201;
```

You get the error:

> ```
> ORA-00936: missing expression
> ```

But, if you use a quoted identifier with the correct case then you can query the table:

```sql
select * from manager where "NUMBER" = 201;
```

Which outputs:

> | NUMBER | SOMETHING |
> | --- | --- |
> | 201 | *null* |

*Note: In Oracle, `''` and `NULL` are identical.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=565ec4cc2362d6480e7f1af4f8d068a0)*